# Is it possible to get the node or parent node from cursor location or index in AceEditor?

Tags: ace-editor

I have an editor that is populated with the contents of an XML document. Is it possible to get the node that the user has placed his cursor in or the parent node if it's in "text.xml" token?

I just remembered I might have asked this a few years ago. I'll try and find it.